# Fixed width select box dropdown expand towards left side

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<select>
<option>Compressed and uncompressed copies of jQuery files are available</option>
<option>Compressed and uncompressed copies of jQuery</option>
<option>Compressed and uncompressed</option>
</select>
</div>
```

js

```
function fixIeCombos() {

    //if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) 
    //{ 
    $('select').wrap('<div class="selectDiv"></div>');
    $('.selectDiv').width($('select').outerWidth());
    $('select')
    .bind('focus mouseover', function() {            
        var originalWidth = $(this).width();    
        var $selectClone = $(this).clone();
        $selectClone.addClass('expand');
        $(this).after( $selectClone );
        var expandedWidth = $selectClone.width();
        $selectClone.remove();
        if (expandedWidth > originalWidth) {
            $(this).addClass('expand').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).parent().css({'border-left':'solid 1px #ccc'});
        }
    })
    .bind('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked'); 
    })
    .bind('mouseout', function() {        
       if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
           $(this).removeClass('expand');
       $(this).parent().css({'border-left':'solid 0px #ccc'})
        }        
    })
    .bind('change', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('expand');
    $(this).parent().css({'border-left':'solid 0px #ccc'});
    })
    .bind('blur', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('expand clicked');
    $(this).parent().css({'border-left':'solid 0px #ccc'});
    })
   // }
}
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/* For Select Box*/
select{
    width:200px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
select.expand { 
    width: auto; 
}
.selectDiv {
    overflow:hidden;    
}
.selectDiv select {
    float:right;
}
```

select option truncated in IE. So I've used the above script for avoiding the truncate. So it working like options are expand toward left in IE8 but not in IE7, because options are expand towards right and `float:right` property not working for select box in IE7.

My problem is, options are expand towards left in IE7 too.

Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kSESt/1/) in IE8 and IE7 browser.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: i want options expand towards left for both IE7 and IE8.